# Make foreach loop argument more efficent

Tags: c#, foreach

Quick question, I have written this code (and it works perfectly)

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("camera").Where(info => info.Element("group").Value == "A"))
{
    A.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
}
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("camera").Where(info => info.Element("group").Value == "B"))
{
    B.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
}
```

Is there a way I could make this more efficient? In particular, I am wondering if the `foreach` loops could be fused together in some way, and/or the argument inside the `foreach` loop could be made easier somehow...

Comment: Sorry, one has the XML element equal to "A", the other "B", slight error

Comment: can you update your question with xml ? so that we can get more idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("camera"))
{
    var value = element.Element("group").Value;
    if (value == "A")
        A.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
    else if (value == "B")
        B.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
}
```

Although I would just use Linq

Comment: Even better than my answer, fewer tests to see which condition we are in.

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou! I wanted to use linq too, but unfortunately I need to manually add different groups, so linq wouldn't work so well (I think, though I'm just starting with C#)

Comment: You are rigth, better leave my answer as is

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can merge the two loops together, you just need the results set to include both sets of data then test correctly inside the foreach loop

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants("camera")
                                 .Where(info => info.Element("group").Value == "A") || 
                                                info.Element("group").Value == "B"))
{
    if(element.Element("group").Value == "A")
        A.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
    else
        B.Items.Add(AddToGroup(element));
}
```

if you had more elements just use `else if` statements to chain the tests along.